# Change color of a cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say i have a list of 100 items. I want to automatically change the color of a specific cell of the item based on whether that item has been sold partially or not. So like if i have 100 quantities of this stock, if it's still 100 after one month then it should be red. Otherwise it should be changed to green if sales are made within that month.

Sorry if this is simple, much appreciated!

Comment: A list of 100 items has no info about the dates. How do you know the dates? Show your data and the desired result (and what you've tried).

Comment: Assuming that you have all the data needed on the sheet, there should be a way to do this with conditional formatting.

Comment: I have a completed worksheet which has all the dates and the months. What i want is that as long as the value in the cell of the item is changed as a result of the formula in another cell, it is highlighted.

Comment: I run this business where i have more than 800 of different items and sometimes i just wanna scroll through to see which items have been inactive

Comment: echoing L. Scott Johnson. The answer will depend on how the data is structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information this can be easily achieved using conditional formatting

I have populated a sample data below

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW9C7.jpg)

Using conditional formatting , you need to set two rules

1. Turn Cell background to red if no values present in row
2. Turn cell background to green values present in row

Considering the sample data above, you need to select the Cells from C2 to C4 and create conditional formatting -> New rules -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

[Rule 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbV95.jpg)

then create one more rule

[Rule 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzgfH.jpg)

it should look like this in summary

[summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNLJR.jpg)

Click apply and you will have the result required

Comment: Hi friend, this works only if comparing to the result of previous month. What i want to achieve is live result https://imgur.com/a/lkVUqyr

Comment: Noted, check again I have updated the conditional formatting rules to fit your needs.

Comment: yes this is what i'm looking for! Appreciated a lot my friend!